# Is there a way to add flv video to video.js player in Wordpress?

Tags: video-player

Video.js supports mp4, wemb and ogg formats but i think there is a trick to add flv format example: http://jsfiddle.net/N8Zs5/18/

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is your _question_ here? What exactly you are trying to achieve and how your code examples relate to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly add flv video to any post/page by using Add Media button. If you want to add a video manually (I mean directly using link of video), then you can use [video] shortcode. This video shortcode supports 'flv' format.

[WordPress Codex documentation of video shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode) explains more about it.